# Uniformly continuous bijection from $X$ to the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $C$ be the Cantor set (equipped with the standard topology).

> Let $f: X\to C$ be a uniformly continuous function. Assume that $f$ is
>   a bijection. Does it follow that $f$ is a homeomorphism?

I know that if $X$ is compact, then the answer is yes. This follows from the following theorem:

> A continuous bijection from a compact set to a Hausdorff space is
>   homeomorphism.

I am hoping that the condition "uniform continuity" is strong enough to cover the case even when $K$ is not compact.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: But if $X$ is not compact, then the homeomorphism cannot exist, because $C$ itself is compact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be the discrete metric on the Cantor set $C$, and let $d$ be the usual metric; then the identity map from $\langle C,\rho\rangle$ to $\langle C,d\rangle$ is a uniformly continuous bijection but not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that this is vacuosly true: $X$ *must* be compact for the homeomorphism to exist, since $C$ itself is compact. IF $f$ is uniformly continuous, or no matter how nice $f$ is, if $X$ is not compact, then no map from $X$ to $C$ can be a homeomorphism, because $C$ is compact. And if $X$ is compact, then, like you said, you have a continuous bijection, which is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Nice perspective! (+1)

Comment: Thanks, Prism; from my old days of point-set topology, I guess something stayed with me.